# how to save a numeric format in csv

Tags: excel, csv, numeric

my problem is that as soon as I am saving my excel sheet in csv. the content is not seen as numeric anymore. I can't save it. It's a big problem, because when importing the csv. in R, the numbers are mixed up, because the R doesn't recognize the numbers as ascending numbers.

Comment: See what google say -->  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216023

Comment: Excel's csv are garbage unless you use a macro program to generate them (google around...) Besides, several packages in R do a decent job in importing data from Excel,

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me there is an option in saving CSV to save the format as the first line. Without that you will have to specify the format each time manually, unless it happens to guess correctly.